# Spring JPA unknown error but application works as expected

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm using Spring 4.0, tomcat 8, spring-data-jpa 1.7.0.RELEASE, hibernate 4.1, mysql 5.6.21 Homebrew. I'm new in java, just moved form C++ background. I assume there must be some resource leaking. I have to close or free something before I exist the app. But no idea what to do. Please advise me!

Every time I restart I got following error:-

```
  Nov 20, 2014 2:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase  
 clearReferencesThreads 
 WARNING: The web application [MyJap] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL 
 Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a 
 memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
  java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
 Nov 20, 2014 2:01:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
```

Comment: Can this be a cause? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264535/mysql-statement-cancellation-timer-in-waiting-state-in-grails-2-2-4-with-jdbc-po

Comment: Or you can just move JDBC configs to Tomcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632153/tomcat7-jdbc-datasource-this-is-very-likely-to-create-a-memory-leak. In java world we are spoiled and mostly, solve this with restart :)